# How to add and remove class dynamically to child div based on value in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

if data value is matching with any div inside requestsampler class then dynamically add new class(sampleClass) to test class inside the matching container

js:

```
var data = **somevalue**;
```

data is dynamic value

html:

```
<div class="requestsampler">
  <div class= "**somevalue**">
    <div class="test">  // add new class <div class="test sample class">
     //
    </div>
    
  </div>
   <div class= "somevalue2">
     <div class="test">
      //
    </div>
    
  </div>
   <div class= "somevalue3">
     <div class="test">
      //
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

tried not working:

```
$('.requestsampler').hasClass(data) {
  $(.'requestsampler .`${data}` .test').addClass('sampleclass');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use Attribute Contains Prefix Selector [name|="value"] for more info please refer http://jqapi.com/#p=attribute-contains-prefix-selector.. below is the code for your example.

```js
  $(document).ready(()=>{
    var data = "somevalue"; $('div[class|="'+data+'"]>.test').addClass("sampleclass");
    })
```

```css
   .sampleclass{
      background-color:red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="requestsampler">
      <div class= "somevalue">
        <div class="test">  // add new class <div class="test sample class">
         //
        </div>
        
      </div>
       <div class= "somevalue2">
         <div class="test">
          //
        </div>
        
      </div>
       <div class= "somevalue3">
         <div class="test">
          //
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can we add "somevalue" dynamically in that condition? // var data ="somevalue";
how to have data instead of hard code "somevalue"

Comment: Yes offcourse we can add it just concatenate the  variable in the selector. For example if data contains your somevalue the selector would become $('div[class|="'+data+"']>.test').addClass("sampleclass")

Comment: Have Edited the code snippet to add "somevalue" dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

you could try jquery **[`elem.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** api. And also use `className` with string and numeric combination instead of `symbols`

> i have changed the condition with element find length. Because `hasClass()` only perform on the selector element. So if you are using `find()` they will find the matched element.

*And also your if condition does not make any sense, without condition is also working same*

**Updated**

If you need first `test` element. use `.eq(0)` or else use different className for the first test element

```js
var data = "somevalue";
if ($('.requestsampler').find(`.${data}`).length > 0) {
  $('.requestsampler').find(`.${data}`).find('.test').eq(0).addClass('sampleclass');
}
```

```css
.sampleclass {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="requestsampler">
  <div class="somevalue">
    <div class="test"> // add new class
      <div class="test sample class">
        sample
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="somevalue2">
      <div class="test">
        //
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="somevalue3">
      <div class="test">
        //
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: this solution is adding sampleclass for all 3